# Pagination showing all results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I'm retrieving my data from an external source so having to build pagination manually. However it only outputs all results, at first I thought this might be because my array has Objects inside but appears it happens in both cases. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

class MainController extends BaseController {
    // Base controller specifies layout
    // protected $layout = 'master';
    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->title = 'testing';
        $this->layout->main = View::make('testing');

        $objArray = array();
        $entry = new \stdClass();
        $entry->title = "testing";
        $objArray[] = $entry;
        $objArray[] = $entry;
        $objArray[] = $entry;
        $objArray[] = $entry;

        $this->layout->main->paginated = Paginator::make($objArray, count($objArray), '2');
        // var_dump($paginated->count()); // returns 4

        $array = array(
            array('title' => 'test'),
            array('title' => 'test'),
            array('title' => 'test'),
            array('title' => 'test')
        );

        $this->layout->main->arrayPaginated = Paginator::make($array, count($array), '2');
        // var_dump($arrayPaginated->count()); // returns 4
    }

}
```

View file

```
## view/testing

@foreach($paginated as $entry)
    {{$entry->title}}
@endforeach
{{$paginated->links()}} //outputs "testing" four times

@foreach($arrayPaginated as $entry)
    {{$entry['title']}}
@endforeach
{{$arrayPaginated->links()}} //outputs "test" four times
```

Comment: What u mean only outputting all results only ?

Comment: You have to slice the array for pagination. [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: If you use `Paginator::make` you need to pass as array only elements that should be displayed for specific page and not all elements. Of course if you take data from database you don't have to do it but if you have some complex data that you need to create manually you need to do it on your own

Comment: I need to build the pagination part myself? so using the examples I have, I would have to break the arrays up, so they only have 2 entries each? if so, what is the use of the param "items per page"?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments you have to slice the array yourself, one thing I can't understand though is what's the user of the third parameter *"Items per page"* if you have to limit the entries before passing it to the paginator.

```
$objArray = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $entry = new \stdClass();
    $entry->title = "test {$i}";
    $objArray[] = $entry;
}

$perPage = 2;
$page = Input::get('page', 1); // Set default to 1 if nothing is passed
// ($page - 1) so that when page is 1 you are targetting the start of the array

$pagedData = array_slice($objArray, ($page - 1) * $perPage, $perPage);
$this->layout->main->paginated = Paginator::make($pagedData, count($objArray), $perPage);
```

Nothing changed in the view file.